# Using pinned certificates with AVPlayer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, certificate-pinning

Is there a way to get AVPlayer to enforce certificate pinning in iOS?

Our video loading code is basically:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.mp4")!
let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
```

We're able to do certificate pinning with URLSession using this delegate method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondelegate/1409308-urlsession. But I haven't been able to figure out an analogous approach for AVPlayer, if there is one.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant method to implement should be this one in `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetresourceloaderdelegate/1388736-resourceloader)):

```swift
optional func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, 
     shouldWaitForResponseTo authenticationChallenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge) -> Bool
```

In your case, create an `AVURLAsset` directly, and set your delegate implementation on its resource loader. Then initialize the player item with the asset.

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.mp4")!
let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
urlAsset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(resourceLoaderDelegate,
                                    queue: .main)
let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: urlAsset)
```